# Selenium IDE - verification of auto-fill text in a text-box

Tags: textbox, selenium-ide, autofill

I have a text box and some data gets auto-filled in that text-box and I need to know that the text present is correct using Selenium IDE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many ways you can achieve this, and which one you have to use varies depending on how your application behaves. There is no straight way to answer which unless we see the actual application.

There are many commands that can help you. verifyValue [image: verifyValue Example], verifyText, & verifyTextPresent, & assertTextPreset etc

Right click on the fields that has prefilled values... You will find an option ShowAvailableCommands in the context menu, move into that option , you will find various ways you can achieve what you wanted. Hope it helps...
[image]